# bi folding pantry door to frosted single door?

Tags: doors, kitchens

I have a brand new home, and in the kitchen is a bi folding door on a track for pantry. I am looking to convert it to one of those frosted doors. Can I just put this on hinges to the wall? Or do i need to get it as a pre hung door and install it with a door jamb, and remove the drywall around it etc? Having trouble finding information as a DIYer for this.

Currently there is no trim around bi folding doors. Just the painted dry wall with notches cut out at floor baseboard and trim.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You can hang a door however you like. Whether it meets your needs is completely up to you.

Comment: The standard door for a pantry is supposed to allow visibility into the pantry. I suppose this is a hold-over from large estates where pilfering had to be controlled, or perhaps for observation to uncover rodent infestation. To replace the bi-fold pantry door in our house my wife picked out a custom-made pre-hung screen door with a copper screen to allow airflow, but keep out rodents. I laid in a threshold over the ceramic tile floor that fits to less than 1/8 inch from the bottom of the door.

Comment: We had metal bi-fold doors and when our border collie would give the pantry door a stiff jab it would resound like a drum. Her technique was  thump the door with one paw and then stare at us with her luminous yellow eyes. It *was* very effective in her getting a treat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you mean. your bi-fold door does not have door jamb because it does not need one. You can not just mount a door on hinges to the wall, you need a jamb, pre hung door or build a jamb.

The issue you need to deal with is the size of the opening.  The size of the  pre hung door you want to put in the opening is dependent on the size of the opening. Measure your opening ( this is your "rough opening' I.E. RO )  and get a door with an RO the next size smaller, you can go larger but it requires removing framing instead of adding framing.   You NEED  an RO that is specific to the door you buy, if you are lucky your RO will not need to be modified but is is unlikely.

The  thickness of your Sheetrock on the inside of you current opening is likely 1/2 inch on both sides so if you cut it out you gain an inch. If you have to make it smaller you can put in a 2x4 and shim it so that it gives you the RO you need but this means patching in Sheetrock if the amount you ad is wider than the trim you want to use. So measure your opening  and determine what the best door size is, i would say one size smaller, and then get back to us. You can do it if you are handy. If you are in Alaska i can help Or fly me there. :)

The bottom line is you need a RO that is the correct size for the required RO of the door you buy, then you need to hang the door correctly and trim it out.

Comment: Thanks! I see they have bi folding doors with frosted glass as well, but in the long run the full door will probably look better. Instead of a flight, will a rental car do? 

Answer (score 1):

I replaced several bi-fold doors with pre-hung and for all but one I removed the drywall down to the rough 2x4 framing. For one thing this allowed standard doors to fit.

For one narrow closet of odd size I got a custom pre-hung door and did not remove drywall. I didn't remove the drywall because the interior dry wall face extended all the way out the outside. There must be a name for this kind of closet.

Comment: Also make sure the opening is plumb. When the framers know that bi-fold doors are being used I think they take less care in framing. If the opening is not plumb, then you will have to do surgery on the rough opening to get the pre-hung door (which is a rectangle) to fit inside a parallelogram. Usually this means cutting the rough framing high on one side and low on the opposite side.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jim. When they were building the house and tbe drywall went up, they left the inside door frame just the wood. So I wasn't sure if there was a specific reason, but good to know I may not have to strip it.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no drywall on the insides of the (4.5 inch wide) door frames, that the 2x4 framing is exposed? Was this covered by some special trim that came with the bi-fold doors? If so, that makes your life easier. In our house there were drywall strips (about 4.5 " wide). At least they used just paper tape for the outside corners--no metal bead--so it was relatively easy to remove the drywall on the insides of the door frames.

Comment: One or more pictures of your doors and the sidewall would be helpful.